# Cypress not retrying assertion

Tags: cypress

My Cypress test is acting inconsistently due to an assertion set on header text. Here is my code:

```
cy.get('.heading-large').should('contain', 'dashboard') // passes
cy.contains('View details').first().click()
cy.get('.heading-large').should('contain', 'Registration details') // sometimes fails
```

If it fails, it is because the heading still contains 'dashboard' - Cypress appears not to have retried but gives error `Timed out retrying: expected '<h1.heading-large>' to contain 'Registration details'`

From reading about [Cypress retry-ability](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/retry-ability.html#Commands-vs-assertions), my understanding is that the `should` assertion should keep trying until timeout, which is set as `"defaultCommandTimeout" : 5000`. This feels true even if I have an element with the same identifier across two pages. There are no major performance issues with the app I'm testing.

The test seems more likely to fail if I am not watching the window and [this issue](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/5023) looks like a possible cause.

Can anyone help determine: is there an issue with my test or Cypress, and how might I improve the test? I'm using Cypress 5.1.0 and Chrome 85 on MacOS Catalina.

Comment: Did you try `.click({ force: true })` as suggested late in the 'Some tests flake only if test runner's browser loses focus (or run headlessly)' issue? Some elements do not have [actionability](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/interacting-with-elements.html#Actionability) because of CSS settings, and `{ force: true }` tells Cypress to bypass the rules.

Comment: Thanks eric99, I've just tried it but still got the same assertion error when the window was out of focus. It's looking increasingly like I need to wait for the [flake issue](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/5023) to be resolved, and watch the tests running in the meantime!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is failing occasionally because the request that fills the header with information has not resolved by the time the timeout has been reached.

You can solve this by setting up a route with a route alias to wait for that exact response from the request to resolve before you proceed with the click.

In other words, When you `click()`, there is a request sent that grabs the information you want to check for in the next `get()`. This response for this request has sometimes not resolved by the time your `get()` reaches timeout. You could increase the timeout but that's not recommended and not good practice here. Instead, wait for that specific response with route & route alias. If you do that, in every case, the last `get()` won't get called until the information it is looking for has been resolved.

I don't know your request but it would work something like this:

```
// setup the route and alias
cy.server()
cy.route("/youRequestUrlHere").as("myLovelyAlias")

// first get 
cy.get('.heading-large').should('contain', 'dashboard')
// this click fires the request url from route() above
cy.contains('View details').first().click()

// wait for route to resolve using route alias
cy.wait("@myLovelyAlias").then((response) => {
  // next get called after response resolves
  cy.get('.heading-large').should('contain', 'Registration details')
}
```

Reference:

- [Route & alias](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases.html#Routes)
- [Route](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/route.html#Syntax)
- [Best Practice - get()](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/best-practices.html#Unnecessary-wait-for-cy-get)
- [Network Request - wait()](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/network-requests.html#Waiting)

edit:

As mentioned above, you could also cheat and set the defaultCommandTimeout to a higher number but that is not recommended because you could still run into cases where the response resolution takes longer than the timeout you've set. The route/wait pattern is the better, more stable approach.

Just in case you want to know how its done though, you would change your `get()` to something like:

```
cy.get('.heading-large', {defaultCommandTimeout: 60000}).should('contain', 'Registration details')
```

Again, other way would be much better.

Reference:

- [Cypress configuration](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration.html#Timeouts)

Comment: Thank you Old Schooled! It is helpful to understand the best practice around aliasing. My test still behaves the same way however. Having tried your suggestion and run it a few more times, it looks like the issue is more with how Cypress is dealing with the window not being in focus. I have voted your response up but it's not yet visible as I'm new!

Comment: I'm sorry that wasn't the solution to your problem. :(

Comment: Thank you, I don't think it's the root cause in this case, but I've definitely learnt something useful :)

Comment: Answer accepted as it has helped narrow down the root cause and pointed me to useful ways to make tests more resilient :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like we need to wait for the Cypress bug "[Some tests flake only if test runner's browser loses focus (or run headlessly)](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/5023)" to be fixed. This is because I have tried the alternative, helpful answers but am consistently facing the original issue when the window is out of focus.

Thank you to those who have answered and commented.